# IntelliJ IDEA debugger navigation keyboard shortcuts

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In IntelliJ IDEA, how do I go from Frames to Variables in the Debug view without using my mouse?

[image]

Comment: IE: how do I move the focus from left to right or how is that action named so I can assign it a shortcut.

Comment: You can't: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167805

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from 2019.3 version you can do it with "Show List of Tabs" action CTRL + ↓ (⌃ + ↓ for Mac). It allows navigating between any debug toolwindow tabs with any tabs layout.